# Call to a member function fails() on a non-object in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

FatalErrorException in RegistersUsers.php line 32: Call to a member function fails() on a non-object In Laravel 5

Please help to solve this problem I am thankful for who can solve this error.
The code in the RegistersUsers.php is

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait RegistersUsers
{
use RedirectsUsers;

/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
}
```

Controller code and the controller name is AuthController.php

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

 class AuthController extends Controller {

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

 public function validator(array $data){}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
 */
public function create(array $data){}

 }
```

Comment: Then `$this->validator()` didn't return an object? In fact, you seem to return nothing.

Comment: So what's value should need to return to solve this error.

Comment: It needs to return something that implements [`Validator`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Validator.html), perhaps by using the [`ValidatorFactory`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Factory.html).

Comment: Thank for your comment But Still I have confuse which value is return to implement validator.

Answer (score 0):

Create request by using this command in terminal

```
php artisan make:request Name_of_request
```

In requests file create rules under rules() method. For example

```
public function rules()
{        
          return [
                'title' =>  'required|min:3',
                'body'  =>  'required',
                'tag_list'  =>  'required',
                'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
            ];
 }
```

After creating rules add the class on Controller like below.

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request){
   //Your codes
}
```

> ArticleRequest is the request class and $request is the post object.

Answer (score 0):

In you Auth Controller to need to include 'use Validator;'.

Also your validate and create methods are empty. Those methods should look something like this:

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
         return Validator::make($data, [
           'name'       => 'required|max:255',
           'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
           'password'   => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
       ]);
}

public function create(array $data)
{
        return User::create([
           'name' => $data['name'],
           'email' => $data['email'],
           'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       ]);
}
```

Comment: Oh and also include your user model "use App\User;"